# javascript not working on dynamically added tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am facing a strange bug at the moment, involving javascript. I have used jquery ui tabs to dynamically add and remove tabs in my website, the content of the tab contains two buttons which upon mouseover dissappear and become visible on mouseleave of the relevant link at the bottom. This mouseover is working fine for the first default tab but not for dynamically added tabs. when i mouseover the content of the new tab the effect is not happening. Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Hunain/E2nJa/
this fiddle is not exact as my result and doesn't contain my issue so please read my above statement correctly, because i have explained the issue
i have used following code for mouseover

```
$("#butt").mouseenter(function () {
            $("#butt").css("visibility","hidden");
          })
          $("#info").mouseleave(function () {
            $("#butt").css("visibility","visible");
          });
```

Comment: Use jquery.on(.... for content getting added dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding  the event on document load and adding button after the binding the event. So event will not bind with the element which added later.
You should bind event after adding buttons.

Comment: -1 As many others have noted, the proper way of handling dynamically added content is to delegate the listener to a persistent parent element, NOT attach a new listener after every time dynamic content is added.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` only work for **items that exist in the DOM on page load**

You need to use a delegated event: `on` for jQuery 1.7+, or `delegate` for earlier versions.

Try this (`on`):

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", "#butt", function () {
    $(this).css("visibility","hidden");
});

$("body").on("mouseleave", "#butt", function () {
    $(this).css("visibility","visible");
});
```

Or this for pre-1.7 (`delegate`):

```
$("body").delegate("#butt", "mouseenter", function () {
    $(this).css("visibility","hidden");
});

$("body").delegate("#butt", "mouseleave", function () {
    $(this).css("visibility","visible");
});
```

Comment: i get your point, but if you look at the fiddle, mouseleave event is on another div #info, the visibility is toggled on #butt, but it is visible only when mouseleave is done on #info, how is this possible with on/delegate

Comment: I have done the on/delegate event, but still, when the newly created tab is active and i mouse over its same content, nothing happens, it should do the same thing and toggle visibility, but it doesn't. if i click the previous[original] tab, and mouse over its content, the effect is still there...

Comment: @Hunain Hmm, do you have duplicate IDs in your HTML? Can you post it?

Comment: yes the newly created tab has duplicated ids, is that the problem? but isn't the content in-accessible, when it is inactive i.e when it is not used or the dynamic tab is clicked?

Comment: I have also used class now, still nothing, but when i viewed it in developer tools now, the visibility is toggling but only when the newly created dynamic tabs are inactive, so the effect is not viewable, upon making it active the effect doesn't happen :p

Answer (score 1):

with reference to your fiddle...

```
$("#butt").mouseenter(function () {
     $("#butt").css("visibility", "hidden");
 })
```

it should be like this

```
$jQuery.on("mouseenter","#butt",function () {
     $("#butt").css("visibility", "hidden");
 });
```

Same goes for other elements which you know are going to be added at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

use `on` delegated events...

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "#butt", function () {
  $(this).css("visibility","hidden");
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", "#butt", function () {
  $(this).css("visibility","visible");
});
```

you can read through this [post](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) if you want to know more about `on` direct and delegated  event

it is better if you delegate it to closest static element that is present in the document rather than to `document` or `body` for better performance

Comment: i get your point, but if you look at the fiddle, mouseleave event is on another div #info, the visibility is toggled on #butt, but it is visible only when mouseleave is done on #info, how is this possible with on/delegate

Comment: that is because if a look at the newly created tab.. the `<b id="butt".. > ` doesnot exists....so the selector won't be able to find that

Comment: It exists alright, i have checked it using developer tools, it is plain old jquery tab at work, when i click on the newly added dynamic tab the previous tab is not active anymore, the new tab content is active, and there is same id='butt' there also, still nothing...

Comment: sorry for late... but thn you will have two ids with the same name which is not valid...and i guess mouseenter and mouseleave event is trigerring for the first one which is invisible... so use class instead of id... that should work